# Does not name a type, but why?

Tags: c++

I have this header:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum _TYPE {_FUNCTION,_SYMBOL};

class consoleApi
{
public:
    void _consoleWrite(string arg1)
    {
        cout << arg1;
    }
};

consoleApi _consoleApi;

class dataKeyword
{
public:
    string _name;
    _TYPE _type;
    int _argumets;
    void (*_pointer)(string);
};

dataKeyword _dataKeyword[128];

_dataKeyword[0]._name="consoleWrite";
_dataKeyword[0]._type=_FUNCTION;
_dataKeyword[0]._argumets=1;
_dataKeyword[0]._pointer=&_consoleApi._consoleWrite;
```

When I try to compile this, CodeBlocks throw these errors:
    error: '_dataKeyword' does not name a type|
    error: '_dataKeyword' does not name a type|
    ... etc.

I know what it usually means, but not in this case. What's wrong?

Comment: Statements can only appear inside of a function.

Comment: And don't put `using namespace std` in header files.

Comment: There's sufficient information in the question to determine where he's gone wrong. He didn't strip out anything necessary.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ye I know, It was writed only to avoid errors, I already moved it but forgot to remove it from one of the headers.

Comment: @Puppy These errors pop on lines:
_dataKeyword[0]._name="consoleWrite";
_dataKeyword[0]._type=_FUNCTION;
_dataKeyword[0]._argumets=1;
_dataKeyword[0]._pointer=&_consoleApi._consoleWrite;

Comment: **Never** use identifiers containing a double-underscore, or starting with underscore+uppercase letter. Those are reserved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have arbitrary statements at global scope. Statements must be part of a function (or something similar, such as a class's constructor).

All you can have at global scope is declarations. Declarations start with a keyword or a type name. The compiler sees `_dataKeyword`, knows it's at global scope, knows `_dataKeyword` is neither a keyword nor a type name, so immediately flags this as an error.

You can initialise an array directly in the declaration, depending on the array element type, but to use statements to assign to the elements, those statements need to be in a function.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `_pointer` is a function pointer. `dataKeyword::consoleWrite` is a member function. These cannot be bound to regular function pointers, since there is no "`this`" argument. You can get a member function pointer to it, which has allowances for "`this`".  You cannot ever take the address of a member function of an object directly, you can only take the address of the member accessed through the class.

Also, all `_UPPERCASE` names are *strictly* reserved for the implementation. You are invoking undefined behaviour by using them.

Also, all `_something` names are reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: True, but you didn't actually identify the problem that's causing _these_ errors.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips, but this still doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

In C++, everything at the namespace level must be declarations.

```
_dataKeyword[0]._name="consoleWrite";
_dataKeyword[0]._type=_FUNCTION;
_dataKeyword[0]._argumets=1;
_dataKeyword[0]._pointer=&_consoleApi._consoleWrite;
```

These are statements, not declarations. They can only appear in function bodies.